# Resizing Activity Indicator in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, resize, activity-indicator

I am trying to resize an ActivityIndicator (in Xamarin.Forms), but the `Scale` property does not work and the `HeightRequest` just crops the ActivityIndicator.

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" IsRunning="True" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is the result.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

It seems sizing itself is not supported on the `ActivityIndicator`. In this case, scaling is your friend.

The cutting-off you see happening is because the `ActivityIndicator` is inside a `StackLayout`. Because of how a `StackLayout` works, it will only take up the space it needs. Since scaling doesn't necessarily make your `ActivityIndicator` bigger, you have two options:

- Replace your `StackLayout` with a `Grid`
- Give your `ActivityIndicator` a `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` that is big enough to keep your scaled `ActivityIndicator`

Note: Talking about iOS here. Width and height seem to work on Android

Comment: The xaml posted by Martin works fine for me, even I can increase or decrease height of indicator `ActivityIndicator` that adjust according. It means the issue should be in total xaml what Marin might have.

Comment: What Xamarin.Forms version are you using?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0.871581. Shouldn't it work for me?

Comment: Hm no, I can't influence the width by using `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`. Do you have any code or maybe a sample repository to share?

Comment: In my xaml file I have exactly & only same code what Martin posted. I can change `WidthRequest` & `HeightRequest` of `ActivityIndicator` & those changes are immediately affecting to previewer window.

Comment: I see, you're talking Android. We are talking iOS :)

Comment: O no! Don’t worry about it! I added a note to the answer for the future readers that it _does_ work on Android. So nothing was wasted!

Comment: My problem occurred on the Xamarin.GTK, where neither of these solutions seem to work. But thank you for your tips.

Comment: Ah! That is also a possibility there days ;-) Unfortunately I'm not able to test GTK right now

Answer (score 4):

Remove `HeightRequest="20"`, it blocks your scale property.

Code should look like this

```
<ActivityIndicator HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Scale="2" IsRunning="True" />
```

Now, you can scale to whatever size you want.